Error when running "cargo generate esp-rs/esp-idf-termplate generate" on Ubuntu
This is the first time I am doing this. I run the following command
cargo generate esp-rs/esp-idf-template cargo
and my project is created.
I then run
cargo build and get the following error message,

I have tried the same thing with the options enabled and have tried all
esp-idf versions ( master, v5.1 and v4.4) with the same results.
I have also tried the same thing in VSC opening the same folder and
then selecting run in the main.rs file. I have rust-analyzer
extension installed.
I tried all the different versions with out success.
I went to crate.io and searched for ESP-IDF-SVC and found
the file as shown below.

It is the same version that appears in the error message 0.48.1.
I then went to documentation and under the crates heading selected esp-idf-svc and then selected source at the top right of the screen.
I then went to line 546 in the source code as show below,

I see there is a lot of code which looks like it is doing version number checks.
I am going currently going through the code ....
Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Please do not upload images of text.

Usually errors like this emitted from a library are considered bugs. I would suggest filing an issue.

I will do that.
